# piping long stdout into tee command sometimes will result in truncation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tee

At few examples I can see that **tee doesn't wait for stdout to finish**, and this results in some buggy behavior. 
first example:
`seq 50000|tee >(wc) >(head -2) >/dev/null`
will output:

```
                1
                2
  12773   12774   65536
```

instead of

```
                1
                2
  50000   50000  288894
```

second example:
`cat f.txt|grep abc|tee f.txt >/dev/null`
at this example, the file update will work, only if the file is a short one, but if the file is a long one, sometimes tee will starts writing before cat finishes, and the file update will work only on the first 'cat' transition.

you can say that tee is only for redirecting to files, but I see also those usages with tee.
I know that pee command doesn't have this bug, but anyone knows a workaround to make tee to wait?
thanks :-)

Comment: `second example` - how can you read and write to the same file at the same time? I don't understand what the second example is about. What is your question?

Comment: as for the second example - I thought that I can cat the file as first step, do some text manipulation, and only then redirect it back to the file... I asked for a way to delay the output at the pipe... 
thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing can be reduced to this:

```
seq 50000 | tee >(wc) >(exit) >/dev/null
```

If one of the streams `tee` writes to returns an error, `tee` terminates. Because pipes are usually buffered with 4K buffer, it is enough for `wc` to grab some lines and process them.

`head -n2` closes the stream after printing two lines.

You can see the error by telling `tee` to print something on errors:

```
# seq 50000 | tee --output-error=exit >(wc) >(exit) >/dev/null
tee: /dev/fd/62: broken pipe
```

You can remove the problem with `-p` or `--output-error=warn` to tell `tee` to continue after errors when writing to pipes:

```
seq 50000 | tee -p >(wc) >(head -n2) >/dev/null
```

or use a command that doesn't exit after processing the input, like `sed`:

```
seq 50000 | tee >(wc) >(sed -n '1,2p') >/dev/null
```

Comment: For macOS users using the system `tee` who end up here, `-p` and `--output-error` are not valid options in the system's default `tee` utility, and `-i` to ignore `SIGINT` doesn't fix this either, so I got it to work by using homebrew and using `gtee` instead: `brew install coreutils`. AND... in my case, with `python manage.py test | gtee outfile` on macos, it wouldn't work when merging STDOUT & STDERR unless I did `2>&1 python -u manage.py test | gtee outfile`. *So many hoops to do what seems like it should be simple, ugh.*